# vscode cannot see emmet result preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Recently i re-installed the vs code but right now i cannot see the preview of emmet result, can anyone give me a solution for getting back a emmet result preview. Thanks

[image: ScreenShoot]

Comment: If you then hit `Ctlr+Space` does it work?  It may not show automatically if you are close to the bottom of the editor.

Comment: @Mark yes if i hit `Ctrl+Space` it work, but it still doesn't show a result preview